# Django annotate and LEFT OUTER JOIN with desired WHERE Clause

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

**Django 1.10.6**

```
Asset.objects.annotate( 
    coupon_saved=Count( 
        Q(coupons__device_id='8ae83c6fa52765061360f5459025cb85e6dc8905') 
    ) 
).all().query
```

**produces the following query:**

```
SELECT
   "assets_asset"."id",
   "assets_asset"."title",
   "assets_asset"."description",
   "assets_asset"."created",
   "assets_asset"."modified",
   "assets_asset"."uid",
   "assets_asset"."org_id",
   "assets_asset"."subtitle",
   "assets_asset"."is_active",
   "assets_asset"."is_generic",
   "assets_asset"."file_standalone",
   "assets_asset"."file_ios",
   "assets_asset"."file_android",
   "assets_asset"."file_preview",
   "assets_asset"."json_metadata",
   "assets_asset"."file_icon",
   "assets_asset"."file_image",
   "assets_asset"."video_mobile",
   "assets_asset"."video_standalone",
   "assets_asset"."file_coupon",
   "assets_asset"."where_to_buy",
   COUNT("games_coupon"."device_id" = 8ae83c6fa52765061360f5459025cb85e6dc8905) AS "coupon_saved" 
FROM
   "assets_asset" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "games_coupon" 
      ON ("assets_asset"."id" = "games_coupon"."asset_id") 
GROUP BY
   "assets_asset"."id"
```

I need to get that `device_id=X` into **LEFT OUTER JOIN** definition below.

#### How to achieve?

Comment: Why not raw SQL queries? It won't harm anyways

Comment: Yes for now I'm working to make it **raw**, but just curious how to do the same in django. I often run into LEFT JOINS problems with Django.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**
The condition should be in `filter`.

```
qs = (
    Asset.objects
    .filter(coupons__device_id='8ae83c6fa52765061360f5459025cb85e6dc8905')
    .annotate(coupon_saved=Count('coupons'))
)
```

If you want only `count > 0` then it can be filtered.

```
qs = qs.filter(coupon_saved__gt=0)
```

---

**Footnotes**: A one to many query is compiled to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in order to be possible to get also base objects (Asset) with zero children. JOINs in Django are based every times on a ForeignKey to the primary key or similarly on OneToOne or ManyToMany, other conditions are compiled to WHERE.

Conditions in annotation (that you used) are possible e.g. as part of [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) but it is more complicated to be used correctly and useful e.g. if you want to get many aggregations with many conditions by one query without subqueries and if a full scan is acceptable. This is probably not a subject of a question.